# Compare Set variable with its previous value, got .has is not a function

Tags: javascript

In each run of my code, `availableGoodsUrlSet` may be assigned new value, which is of type `Set`(for simplicity , I assign it to a date object in the following code), from the second run I want to get the difference of the new `availableGoodsUrlSet` with its previous value, but when I clicked  the `Add a list item` link for a second time in the following code to test, I got

```
Uncaught TypeError: lastAvailableGoodsUrlSet.has is not a function
at options.html:37
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (options.html:37)
```

So how to achieve my goal ?

Simple MutationObserver Example
        
            .invisible {
                opacity: 0;
            }

```
<body>
    <h1>Simple MutationObserver Example</h1>
    <response class="invisible response">Success!</response>
    <ul>
        <li>Pre-existing list item</li>
        <li>Pre-existing list item</li>
    </ul>
    <p><a data-click="add-list-item" href="#">Add a list item</a></p>

    <script>
        var unorderedList = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

        if (unorderedList) {

            var lastAvailableGoodsUrlSet = new Set();

            var observer = new MutationObserver(
                function (mutations) {
                    availableGoodsUrlSet = new Set();

                    date = new Date();
                    availableGoodsUrlSet.add(date);
                    // lastAvailableGoodsUrlSet.add(date);

                    difference =new Set([...availableGoodsUrlSet].filter(x => !lastAvailableGoodsUrlSet.has(x)));

                    console.log("difference--------", difference);

                    lastAvailableGoodsUrlSet=Object.assign({}, availableGoodsUrlSet);

            });

            // pass in the target node and the observer config options
            observer.observe(unorderedList, { childList: true, subtree: true });

            // listen for any clicks on the add-list-item link
            document.querySelector('[data-click="add-list-item"]').onclick = function (event) {
                var newLi = document.createElement("li");

                newLi.innerText = "New list item";
                unorderedList.appendChild(newLi);

                event.preventDefault();
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use  `lastAvailableGoodsUrlSet=Object.assign({}, availableGoodsUrlSet);`
You are changing Set object to pure object which has no method `add`.

In case you need to merge sets, you can do this:

```js
const firstList = new Set([1,2,3]);
const secondList = new Set([3,4,5]);
const result = [...new Set([...firstList, ...secondList])];

console.log(result);
```

To get the difference:

```js
const firstList =  [1, 2, 3];
const secondList = [3, 4, 5];
const result = firstList.filter(x=> !secondList.includes(x));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I updated the post just now. BTW, I want to get the difference , not union of two sets.

Comment: The answer is the same, - Object.assign returns new object which is not any kind of `set`.

Comment: I am not familiar with JavaScript , can you provide the final answer , thanks !

Comment: I've posted how to get the difference between two arrays. However I would suggest to remove Object.assign from your code. It unexpectedly changing your variable types from set to plain object

Comment: I changed `Object.assign` to `lastAvailableGoodsUrlSet=  [...availableGoodsUrlSet]`

Comment: Now you are changing set to an array :( They are not equal :(